# Where does this quote originate from?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

Muhammad said, “In heaven, Mary mother of Jesus, will be one of my wives.”
al-Siyuti (6/395)

Comment: I found this answer by @Medi1Saif to be very good regarding this matter. Please read : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37444/is-the-hadith-mary-mother-of-jesus-will-be-one-of-my-wives-authentic

Comment: @ahmadnazeem he doesn't have the source of the hadith from Suyuti

Comment: By source are you referring to the narrators or where suyuti quoted this in the first place?

Comment: @Jeschu no it doesn't, that post doesn't address the quote from Al-Suyuti

Comment: The question does refer to Al-Sayuti and the answers say in detail that it's based on weak hadith. If you have an other question on it, ask this question.